# Задачка. Массивы в C#

Tags: c#

Доброе время суток!

Есть такая вот задачка:

> Дан целочисленный массив размера N, содержащий ровно два одинаковых элемента. Найти номера одинаковых элементов и вывести эти номера в порядке возрастания.

Как ее правильно решить? :)

У меня только так получилось:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2};
    int last = a.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < last - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < last; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                Console.Write(a[i] + "  " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: так не работает что-то? выглядит верно

Comment: в принципе всё правильно

Comment: А чем это решение не устраивает (кроме ошибки в строке с Write -- по условию задачи надо вывести i и j)? Недостаток решения -- средняя сложность O(n^2). Для уменьшения сложности можно использовать вспомогательный словарь (Dictionary), где ключ -- значение элемента, а значение -- индекс в массиве.

Answer (score 2):

Позвольте и мне с двумя копейками! Команда **break** в Вашем коде мало эффективна, поскольку она прерывает только внутренний цикл. Программа не переходит в окончание (Console.ReadKey), а продолжает циркулировать как ни в чем не бывало. Придумайте что-нибудь, чтобы не тратить зря машинное время. :-)

Comment: согласен, просто подправить вывод:

    Console.WriteLine(a[i] + "  " + i);
    Console.WriteLine(a[j] + "  " + j);

и воспользоваться ``goto``

Comment: попробуйте break(2); или break 2;

Comment: @timka_s. Простите мою безграмотность. А что это такое - break(2);?

Comment: @Spectre. Можно, конечно, и goto, но следует помнить, что команда goto проклята еще разработчиками языка, и проклятие это воспроизводимо переходит на код, содержащий эту команду. Отсюда - многие неприятности.

Comment: Выход сразу на 2 уровня... В некоторых языках есть

Comment: @timka_s, в с# Нету!

@BuilderC, в данном конкретном случае никаких неприятностей не предвидится, да и выхода особо другого нету. А кто вам сказал, что ``goto`` проклята разработчиками  c#?

Comment: @Spectre. Да шучу я, шучу. Я, вообще-то, не имел ввиду С#, а С и С++.
Что касается выходов, их сколько угодно.

Comment: Не знаю в деталях C#, но могу предложить так выйти из обоих циклов

write....   ;last = 1;
break;

Хотя, наверняка, есть более кошерные способы.

Comment: Я и сам так делал, но перешёл на goto. Код с ним стал гораздо понятнее. goto лишь инструмент, а как им пользоваться, решать программисту. Нельзя ненавидеть его за то, что с его помощью можно сильно запутать код. Просто не надо этого делать. Нужно использовать его только в таких случаях, когда он полезен.

Comment: Просто в C# его нет, как и в джаве.

Comment: @mikillskegg, зря вы так: [пруф](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d96yfwee.aspx)

Comment: Тогда goto

Answer (score 1):

Ты что-то не то выводишь. Нужно выводить номера одинаковых элементов, а ты выводишь значение этого элемента и номер первого из них. Исправленный вариант программы.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int[] a={1, 2, 3, 4, 2};
    for (int i = 0; i<a.Length; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<a.Length; ++j)
            if(a[i]==a[j])
            {
                Console.Write(i+" "+j);
                break;
            }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

И не понял, зачем у тебя переменная last, если можно писать a.Length? Он лишь дезинформирует, так как last на самом деле - это элемент, следующий после последнего элемента. Код `a[last]` вызовет ошибку обращения за пределы массива.

Comment: кэширование значения длины массива не такая уж плохая идея.

Comment: Аргументируй, почему? Размер массива ведь не изменяется. Свойство должно читаться очень быстро, так как оно очень простое. Наверное, компилятор даже подставит его в код. Слово "last" дезинформирует. Его можно было бы назвать end.

Comment: @Spectre. Согласен с Вами. Сам делаю так всегда, когда не предполагается изменение массива. При обращении к функции массив прочитывается с начала до конца чертову пропасть раз. Не хватает, правда, CONST int Last;

Comment: Почему все пишут last? last означает "последний". Здесь last - это не последний, а следующий за ним элемент. last должен иметь значение a.Length-1. Сюда больше подходит end.

Answer (score 0):

Данное решение содержит сравнение каждого с каждым и, как уже говорилось выше, имеет сложность N^2. Я бы сначала отсортировал массив (NlogN операций) и потом нашел в нем два последовательно совпадающих элемента (еще N операций). 
примечение: Поскольку выводить нужно индексы, а не числа, то нужно сделать массив с индексами, отсортировав индексы по числам, лежащим по этим индексам.

Comment: Вряд ли здесь будет такой большой массив, что нужно будет это оптимизировать. Я думаю, здесь достаточно решения "в лоб". Особенно, если это учебное задание.

Comment: Именно в учебных задачах такое часто и требуется - чтобы продемонстрировать понимание. Я бы (как принимающий задачу :-) ) обязательно обратил на это внимание.

Comment: Это смотря какой уровень требуется от студента. 1-2 курс можно и в лоб. От старшекурсников надо, конечно, бОльшего потребовать.

Comment: Если массив маленьккий, как в примере, то n небольшой и скорость от сложности практически не зависит. Она больше зависит от скорости выполнения одной операции. Поэтому при маленьких n решение в лоб может быть даже быстрее.